# Virtual Audio Device and Media Foundation on Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: audio, windows-server-2008, virtual, ms-media-foundation

I tried installing  "media foundation"  feature on Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard edition and wasn't able to track it down.
Is there a way to enable "Media Foundation"?

Comment: And your ultimate goal is?

Comment: I would like to have virtual audio devices installed. Although I register them, I don't "See" them. I thought installing the media foundation will solve my issue. any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Media Foundation is core Windows API, is built into operating system and does not exist as a separate installation/redistributable.

The problem with virtual device you are trying to solve has nothing to do with Media Foundation availability. There are several audio APIs, Media Foundation is just one of them. Each API has its own virtual devices. The only, perhaps, virtual device visible on all APIs is kernel driver for WDM audio device: app APIs would eventually wrap this driver as their device. Kernel level video devices are at the same time untypical and hardest to do. In your case, you need a virtual device for the same API you (or target application) will be consuming the device through.